# Find the value of $\frac{\tan \left(30^{\circ}\right)}{\sin\left(20^{\circ}\right)}-\frac{1}{3\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)}$

Tags: trigonometry

Basically, I should simplify this statement using some form of trigonometric equalities to find a rational value. Apparently, the answer is $\frac{4}{3}$. I tried some sum and difference formulas for sine and cosine but i can't seem to simplify further after some point. Here is what i tried:

$$\frac{\tan \left(30^{\circ}\right)}{\sin\left(20^{\circ}\right)}-\frac{1}{3\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{\sin\left(30^{\circ}\right)}{\sin\left(20^{\circ}\right)\cos\left(30^{\circ}\right)}-\frac{1}{3\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{3\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)\sin\left(30^{\circ}\right)-\sin\left(20^{\circ}\right)\cos\left(30^{\circ}\right)}{3\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)\sin\left(20^{\circ}\right)\cos\left(30^{\circ}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{2\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)\sin\left(30^{\circ}\right)+\sin\left(10^{\circ}\right)}{\frac{3}{2}\sin\left(40^{\circ}\right)\cos\left(30^{\circ}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)+\sin\left(10^{\circ}\right)}{\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}\sin\left(40^{\circ}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{4}{3\sqrt{3}}\frac{\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)+\sin\left(10^{\circ}\right)}{\sin\left(40^{\circ}\right)}$$

Comment: Could you use rad?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I managed to solve it. Here is the solution:
$$\frac{\tan\left(30^{\circ}\right)}{\sin\left(20^{\circ}\right)}-\frac{1}{3*\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}*\sin\left(20^{\circ}\right)}-\frac{1}{3*\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{3}\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)-\sin\left(20^{\circ}\right)}{3*\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)*\sin\left(20^{\circ}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}*\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)-\frac{1}{2}*\sin\left(20^{\circ}\right)}{\frac{3}{2}*\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)*\sin\left(20^{\circ}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{\cos\left(30^{\circ}\right)*\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)-\sin\left(30^{\circ}\right)*\sin\left(20^{\circ}\right)}{\frac{3}{2}*\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)*\sin\left(20^{\circ}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{\cos\left(30^{\circ}\right)*\cos\left(20^{\circ}\right)-\sin\left(30^{\circ}\right)*\sin\left(20^{\circ}\right)}{\frac{3}{4}*\sin\left(40^{\circ}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{\cos\left(50^{\circ}\right)}{\frac{3}{4}*\sin\left(40^{\circ}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{4}{3}$$

Comment: Typesetting tip:  You can produce $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, and $\sec x$, $\cot x$ by typing `$\sin x$`, `$\cos x$`, `$\tan x$`, `$\csc x$`, `$\sec x$`, and `$\cot x$`, respectively.

Comment: I was working on the same solution We have that

$$\frac{\tan \left(30^{\circ \:}\right)}{\sin\left(20^{\circ }\right)}-\frac{1}{3\cos\left(20^{\circ }\right)}
=\frac{3\tan \left(30^{\circ \:}\right)\cos\left(20^{\circ }\right)-\sin\left(20^{\circ }\right)}{3\cos\left(20^{\circ }\right)\sin\left(20^{\circ }\right)}
=\frac{\sqrt 3\cos\left(20^{\circ }\right)-\sin\left(20^{\circ }\right)}{3\cos\left(20^{\circ }\right)\sin\left(20^{\circ }\right)}=$$

$$=\frac{2\cos\left(50^{\circ }\right)}{\frac32\sin(40°)}=\frac43 \frac{\cos\left(50^{\circ }\right)}{\sin(40°)}=\frac43$$